# Erro ao iniciar aplicação WPF

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

Ao iniciar minha aplicação, é mostrada uma mensagem de erro. O problema é que eu não consigo localizar a origem do problema. Antes não dava, começou hoje. Achei que pudesse ser alguma configuração, mas não alterei nada no Visual Studio, que me lembre. Uso Visual 2017 (Português) e WPF. Veja a imagem do erro abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está meu App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="inetConn" connectionString="Data Source=NOTEBOOK\Instancia; Initial Catalog=SILOS; User Id=sa; Password=@d123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: como está seu config ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, vou postar meu App.Config na edição do post.

Comment: em um dos erros, fala que o configSections deve ser o primeiro filho, dentro do nó configuration. Acho que pode começar a resolver por ai

Answer (score 1):

A exception diz:

> ConfigurationErrorsException: Apenas um elemento  é permitido por arquivo de configuração e, se presente, deve ser o primeiro filho do elemento

Atualize se config colocando `<configSections>` antes de `<connectionStrings>`, ficando assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="inetConn" connectionString="Data Source=NOTEBOOK\Instancia; Initial Catalog=SILOS; User Id=sa; Password=@d123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Se apertar o botão stop vai parar e quando eu der F5 novamente, vem o problema. Se tem problema eu sei, mas em design não tem, logo esse problema aparece quando eu rodo e na mensagem não me diz onde é a fonte do problema, conforme eu disse no post.

Comment: Ahhhh, entendi ! Agora eu entendi, vou procurar a solução.

Comment: Posta o código onde tem o <configSections> para a gente vê, provavelmente tem duplicidade de tags.

Comment: Não sabia disso, mas como eu coloquei o connectioStrings na frente do configSections, não funcionou. Troquei e funcionou. Eu não sabia disso.

Comment: Ahhh, acabei de editar e você respondeu hahaha. Mas boa pelo menos solucionou !